# How to download old versions of IPA files?

Tags: ios

Is there any a website like "ApkPure" for IPA files, or is there any other ways to download old versions of IPA files?

My goal is to install multiple versions of an ipa file on the latest version of iOS to look at data from installed apps, or to install and look at old versions of an ipa file, not necessarily the latest version of iOS

Answer (score 1):

I found one way to do this, there's a script called 'ipatool-py' which can be [downloaded from GitHub](https://github.com/NyaMisty/ipatool-py#download-old-version).

The only caveat is that you'll need to run the script on a Windows, with iTunes 12.6.5.3 logged into your Apple ID. The script hooks into iTunes to authenticate with the app store and download an IPA that is tied to your Apple ID.

### Lookup Version

Once the prerequisites are installed (see [the guide](https://github.com/NyaMisty/ipatool-py#download-old-version), I recommend using the 'manual' method), you can lookup the version history IDs for an app:

```
python3 main.py lookup --appId 422667065 -c NZ historyver --itunes-server http://127.0.0.1:9000
```

(Using Snapchat here as an example)

### Download

And then once you have found the the version ID that you want (note, this doesn't always directly correlate 1:1 to the published versions in the version history section of the App Store), you can download the IPA:

```
python3 main.py lookup --appId 447188370 -c NZ download --appVerId 837455833 --itunes-server http://127.0.0.1:9000
```

### Install

To install the IPA, AirDrop it from a Mac to your iPhone.

Comment: I've tried to follow the guide and the directions are missing lots of steps for users that  aren't familiar with using python.  So far I've gotten stuck on executing the python3 main.py command.  Where exactly is main.py supposed to be called from?

Comment: you'll need to be in the ipatool-py folder, and then run 'python3 main.py' in the terminal